# How to use pagination with a controller in side show page of another controller?

Tags: grails, groovy

how can I use pagination with a controller in side show page of another controller 
this is my code:

```
plan controller:
 def show = {
  if (!params.max) params.max = 4
  if (!params.offset) params.offset = 0
  def planInstance = Plan.get(params.id)

  def planVoiceServiceListCount  = PlanVoiceService.countByPlan(planInstance)
  def planVoiceServiceList = PlanVoiceService.findAllByPlan(planInstance, [max: params.max as Integer, offset: params.offset as Integer])

  if (!planInstance) {
   flash.message = "${message(code: 'default.not.found.message', args: [message(code: 'plan.label', default: 'Plan'), params.id])}"
   redirect(action: "list")
  }
  else {

   [planInstance: planInstance, 
    planVoiceServiceList: planVoiceServiceList, 
    planVoiceServiceListCount: planVoiceServiceListCount]
   }
 }
```

and plan\show.gsp:

```
<div class="dialog">
  <table align="left">
    <thead>

    <tr>      
      <th>${message(code:'plan.services.voice.label', default:'Voice Service Name') }</th>
      <th>${message(code:'plan.services.voice.label', default:'Voice Service Description') }</th>
      <th>${message(code:'plan.services.voice.maxsessions.label', default:'Max Simultaneous Calls') }</th>
      <th>${message(code:'plan.services.voice.tariff.label', default:'Voice Tariff') }</th>
      <th>${message(code:'plan.services.voice.services.label', default:'Calling Destination Group') }</th>
      <th>${message(code:'plan.services.voice.services.label', default:'Plan Voice Service Minute') }</th>
      <th>${message(code:'plan.services.voice.services.label', default:'Plan') }</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <g:each in="${planVoiceServiceList}" status="i" var="planVoiceServiceInstance">
      <tr class="${(i % 2) == 0 ? 'odd' : 'even'}">
        <gsec:hasRole name='Administrator'>  
        <td><gti:link controller = "planVoiceService" action="show" id="${planVoiceServiceInstance.id}">${fieldValue(bean: planVoiceServiceInstance, field: "voiceService.name")}</gti:link></td>
        </gsec:hasRole>
        <gsec:hasRole name='Company'>  
        <td>${fieldValue(bean: planVoiceServiceInstance, field: "voiceService.name")}</td>
        </gsec:hasRole>
         <td>${fieldValue(bean: planVoiceServiceInstance, field: "voiceService.description")}</td>
        <td>${fieldValue(bean: planVoiceServiceInstance, field: "maxSessions")}</td>
                <gsec:hasRole name='Administrator'>         
        <td><g:link controller="voiceTariff" action="show" id="${planVoiceServiceInstance.voiceTariff.id}">${fieldValue(bean: planVoiceServiceInstance, field: "voiceTariff.description")}</g:link></td>
  </gsec:hasRole>
        <gsec:hasRole name='Company'>         
        <td>${fieldValue(bean: planVoiceServiceInstance, field: "voiceTariff.description")}</td>
  </gsec:hasRole>
        <td>${fieldValue(bean: planVoiceServiceInstance, field: "callingDestinationGroup.name")}</td>
        <td>${fieldValue(bean: planVoiceServiceInstance, field: "planVoiceServiceMinute")}</td>


        <td>${fieldValue(bean: planVoiceServiceInstance, field: "plan.description")}</td>


      </tr>
    </g:each>
    </tbody>

  </table><br /><br /><br /><br />
  <div  class="paginateButtons">
  <g:paginate controller="plan" action="show" 
         total="${planVoiceServiceListCount}" 
         >
  </g:paginate>
  </div>
```

what's error in my code?????? the data appers but when i click to go to second pagenation page null id error appears

Answer (score 1):

```
  <g:paginate controller="plan" action="show" id="${planInstance.id}"
         total="${planVoiceServiceListCount}" 
         >
```

Comment: can you mark the answer as accepted? people will be more responsive to  your question if you do so.

Comment: it is working but there still a problem occured that i have 2 lists in the show page when i click on one of the pagenate button of the lists the 2 lists turned to the second page. is there a way to solve it ????